# HTML: How to change the size of a button so that it has the same size as the icon on it?

Tags: html, css, class, button, styles

I created a button using the help of https://www.css3buttongenerator.com.  I'm now trying to resize the button on my html so that the icon on the button fits on it  perfectly. I want both of them to be the same size so to say. but that webpage is not really helping me.

This is what my code looks like. 
**HTML:**

```
<button class="butn"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="AnzeigeerstellenHilfe"></i></button>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.butn {
  color: #859f38;
    background-color:transparent;
     background-size: 30px !important;
    width: 22px !important;
    height: 22px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
     outline: 0 !important;
}
```

I've been playing with the values on the .css and changing/adding stuff, but no success so far . How can I do it?

Comment: by default it should be the same size without doing anything

Comment: oh so l have to delete the "background-size" values.. that worked! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#icon {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<button class="butn"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="AnzeigeerstellenHilfe"></i></button>

.butn {
   color: #859f38;
   background-color:transparent;
   text-decoration: none;
   border: none;
   outline: 0 !important;
}
```

or use @sao 's answer if you want to resize the icon